# Have any countries that suspended funding to UNRWA restarted, it given doubts about accusations against it?

Tags: united-states, israel, united-nations, intelligence

Israel accused a handful UNRWA employees of taking part in the October 7 attacks and also claimed that 10% of UNRWA employees in Gaza were 'affiliated' with Hamas. As a [consequence](https://www.reuters.com/world/what-is-unrwa-un-palestinian-refugee-agency-2024-01-29/),

> Countries including the United States, Britain, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands and Switzerland have suspended their funding of the agency in the wake of the allegations.

However, a [recent intelligence report](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/feb/22/us-intelligence-unrwa-hamas) by Israel's main international backer, the USA, has cast doubts on those claims. It has emerged that Israel has not shared their claimed evidence with the US. US intelligence assessment is that the first accusation, that a handful employees participated in October 7th, cannot be verified with current information. They assessed the second accusation, that 10% of UNRWA are affiliated with Hamas, to be unlikely. Moreover the report by the US intelligence also notes that there is a possibility that the allegations were distortions driven by Israeli dislike of the UN:

> In addition, the report notes Israel’s dislike towards the UNRWA, two
> sources familiar with it told the Journal. “There is a specific
> section that mentions how Israeli bias serves to mischaracterize much
> of their assessments on UNRWA and says this has resulted in
> distortions,”

Given this assessment of the accusations by the National Intelligence Council, have any countries that suspended funding to the UNRWA taken the decision to restart?

Edit:

Further info has now come out claiming that the allegations were based on testimony [provided by UNRWA employees under torture and duress](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/unrwa-report-says-israel-coerced-some-agency-employees-to-falsely-admit-hamas-links/).

---

Update Finland has [become the latest country to reinstate funding](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2024/mar/22/middle-east-crisis-live-israel-gaza-ceasefire-resolution-un-security-council-benjamin-netanyahu-antony-blinken-latest-updates), stating that there is insufficient evidence of there being any connection between UNRWA and Hamas.

Comment: Which countries had funding suspended? I don't remember who besides the US.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution As per a Reuters article: "Countries including the United States, Britain, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands and Switzerland have suspended their funding of the agency in the wake of the allegations."

Comment: @whoisit: more actually. A bunch of Eastern Europeans too. They don't get listed in the press often because their actual contributions are probably small.

Comment: *"has cast doubts on those claims."*  is misrepresenting your own link.  What it says:  some of it are clearly true (the handful participating, already fired by UNRWA) - **which you neglect to mention**, others are credible but can't be verified.  *low confidence* is a tricky notion to parse in US intelligence-speak as well and is not the same we "don't trust'.  The report does note that Israel tends to "spin" the UN negatively, which is about the only hard info supporting your assertions, but is not a statement of fact either.  Vote to close, phrased and cherry-picked to push a point.

Comment: Btw, not coming from the PoV that throttling aid, or defunding UNRWA, for all its flaws  the main provider of aid, is a good thing.  Only from the PoV that this Q misrepresents what is known and not known about those UNRWA allegations.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, don't know where you get that from. From my link: "the intelligence report, released last week, assessed with “low confidence” that a handful of staff had participated in the attack, indicating that it considered the accusations to be credible though it could not independently confirm their veracity". That clearly _doesn't mean that handful participating is true_.

Comment: It means that they don't know. For the 10% accusation, the link clearly states that the Intelligence report considers it unlikely to be true. I've edited the question to make this distinction clearer.

Comment: This is a reasonable question. Can those of you who voted to close it explain yourselves?

Comment: @BenCohen there were specific people named, so it's something that should have been easy by the skeptics to confirm/deny, right? I know a lot of people assign low confidence to anything Israel says, because Jews, right? But when faced facts still denying them is a bit more than just pure antisemitism.

Comment: Self-answers are ok. Your latest updates are better suited like that.

Answer (score 6):

Insofar, no, not that I'm aware of. But some European countries have actually increased their contributions, although to be fair, these were relatively small to begin with.

E.g. Slovenia [announced](https://english.sta.si/3271230/slovenia-to-further-finance-unrwa-and-send-aid-to-gaza) on Feb 24 they'd be increasing their contribution by 0.5M euros, and provide extra direct assistance by a similar sum. (The Turkish press has [also](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/europe/slovenia-announces-financial-aid-to-un-refugee-agency-for-palestinians/3146377) highlighted this.) The announcements don't mentions the allegations at all, so it's unclear if the US leaks are correlated in any way.

Ireland also [announced](https://www.gov.ie/en/press-release/978dc-tanaiste-announces-20-million-in-support-for-the-un-relief-and-works-agency-unrwa/) 20 M euros funding on Feb 15 (which is about par with their 2023 contributions of 18 million). That announcement was about two weeks after the allegations caused various European countries to suspend their contributions at the end of January.

On Feb 9, Norway [announced](https://www.reuters.com/world/norway-gives-26-mln-unrwa-this-year-more-could-come-2024-02-09) they were maintaining their regular contribution, but that "there may be additional funds from Norway to UNRWA throughout the year".

---

In case someone wants to watch these for further developments, the full list of countries that [*did*](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/2/17/which-countries-are-still-funding-unrwa) suspend their contributions, according to al-Jazeera (updated on Feb 17):

> Australia,
> Austria,
> Canada,
> Estonia,
> Finland,
> Germany,
> Iceland,
> Italy,
> Japan,
> Latvia,
> Lithuania,
> The Netherlands,
> New Zealand,
> Romania,
> Sweden,
> Switzerland,
> United Kingdom,
> United States.

---

Update. It [looks like](https://www.euronews.com/2024/03/09/israel-hamas-war-sea-route-for-gaza-aid-gains-momentum-canada-to-restore-unrwa-funding) Canada might be the first to restore funding. They said it was due to direct assurances from an "interim report from the UN investigation" rather than something in the press though.

> Canada will restore funding to the United Nations relief agency for Palestinians, weeks after the agency, known as UNRWA, lost hundreds of millions of dollars in support following Israeli allegations against some of its staffers in Gaza.
>
> Canada has been reassured after receiving an interim report from the UN investigation of Israel’s allegations, said Ahmed Hussen, Canada's minister of international development.
>
> The Canadian government is due to contribute €16.8 million to UNRWA in April and did not miss a payment as a result of the pause.

Interestingly, a Canadian minister now [says](https://ca.news.yahoo.com/united-states-implored-canada-behind-163531791.html) that the US administration lobbied Canada behind the scenes to resume the funding, even while the US can't do so due to deadlock in Congress on that.

In the meantime, a few other countries have announced resuming their funding of UNRWA, at least partially: Australia, Sweden, Finland and Iceland.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Netanyahu's [announced plan](https://news.yahoo.com/israel-proposes-indefinite-control-over-155418696.html) is to shutter UNRWA permanently, so they'll probably release any intel they have over time, in order to maximize the effect in the Western press/eyes etc.

Comment: Remember Turkey's [media strategy in re Khashoggi killing](https://thehill.com/opinion/international/415272-the-strategy-behind-erdogans-openness-with-journalists/)?

Comment: Anyhow, a day later Sweden announced something similar to Canada https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-68518468